# Image Blob URL from already given Image Blob URL

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I have a doubt with image blob,is it possible to create an Image blob URL with a given image blob URL?
I created a new image blob URL and tried to use it on img tag but it did not work:

I think maybe the error is because of i am creating new Blob inside useEffect !!! ? IDK

Please help me.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        if (socket.current) {
                socket.current.on("msg-recieve", (msg) => {
                const RecieveBlob = new Blob([msg], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
                const RecieveImageURL = URL.createObjectURL(RecieveBlob);
                console.log("msg recieved is ", msg)
                setArrivalMessage({ fromSelf: false, message: msg })
            })
        }
        setNoImage(false)
    }, [])
```

In this code, msg is an image blob URL coming from the server and I want to display that image in the page.  Therefore, I created new Image blob from it.  However, when I use the new Image blob it is not working.

If anybody knows why please help me, Thanks.

Comment: where do you use the value of RecieveImageURL?

Comment: in image tag src .
<img className='imageMsg' src={RecieveImageURL}/>

Comment: you are defining RecieveImageURL in useEffect. so it should be inaccessible in html source

Comment: do you know any solution for that

Comment: you can use useState hook. above useEffect say, const [imageURL, setImageUrl]=useState("")

inside useEffect 
setImageUrl(URL.createObjectURL(RecieveBlob))

Answer (score 0):

If the msg is `String` you shouldn't wrap that in brackets because it makes it an `[String]` or Array of strings so try this:

instead of:
`const RecieveBlob = new Blob([msg], { type: 'image/jpeg' })`;

write:
`const RecieveBlob = new Blob(msg, { type: 'image/jpeg' })`;

P.S. ***But I think you can use the blob URL and set it as an image source in the first place, it would work.***

Comment: Bhat you meant by set it as an image source in the first place

Comment: this is not working also

Comment: @unnikrishnan can you give an example of your `msg`?

Comment: blob:http://localhost:3000/f3a36353-a1a0-4632-a233-e3ae84dba4ff